# Java & ZeroMQ: one task controller (main node) and many workers (task node)

Tags: java, zeromq

I want understand how I can achieve next task distribution scheme:

**TaskController (main node)**

This controller can create jobs, send to the workers and **asynchronously** receive replies from workers.

**Worker (task node)**

Worker receive a new job and **asynchronously** run it, after job is done worker sends result to the TaskController. Worker can receive many jobs and run asynchronously.

Finally, I want to have TaskController (main node) and 3 workers (task node) that receives jobs, **asynchronously** run jobs and replies to the TaskController (main node) that **asynchronously** receives messages and handle.

In all ZeroMQ examples workers are synchronous - one worker can handle one job at one time.

ZeroMQ can help with my task? Or I need another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Dealer and Router sockets can be used for asynchronous communications. See example here : `http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc76`